# Prevent Wordpress Access From Default Permalinks Structure

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to disable/prevent wordpress post from old permalinks structure.

Example, I have custom permalink structure like this:

```
http://blablabla*com/hello-world
```

But that post still can accessed use old permalinks like this:

```
http:/blablabla*com/?p=1
http://blablabla*com/2014/09/01/hello-world
http://blablabla*com/2014/08/hello-world
```

I've tried to remove canonical redirect use this code.

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Seems work, old permalinks not redirected to my new permalink :)
But the problem, :( I want disable other permalinks structure and send 404 error.
I don't care about canoncial redirect, because its new site and not yet indexed by search engine.

So, that post only can visited use my current custom permalink, not other structure.

I want check current URL, if URL not equal with current permalink setting, send 404 error.

Comment: I this you delete your posts, And want to display 404Error when post id doesn't exist?!
Try this: [wp plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-old-slugspermalinks)

Comment: No, but I want send 404error for existing post, if the URL not equal with current permalink settings. I've tried use that plugin before. But doesn't work,because I want to disabled default WordPress permalinks structure, not the slug of each page. By the way... Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Originally published inside the question by the author*</sup>

I found the solution:
Get the current `request_uri`, and get the current post permalink,
then preg_match them. So if the post visited by old / ugly permalinks (or default wordpress permalinks structure), send 404 error.

Comment: Thanks brasofilo :D that simple solution ever and works.